# Getting a table from a class in Lua

Tags: class, lua

Quick question, how would I get the table called props from the SimpleClass variable?

```
local SimpleClass = {}
local SimpleClass_mt = {__index = SimpleClass}

function SimpleClass:new()
    local props = {name = " yolo"}
    setmetatable(props, SimpleClass_mt)
    return props
end

--get props from SimpleClass here

--my attempt here
local propsFromSimpleClass = getmetatable(SimpleClass)--clearly won't work
```

Comment: I have already made several failed attempts, but I will post it nonetheless to meet your criteria.

Comment: `local propsFromSimpleClass = SimpleClass:new()`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're a misleading yourself a bit.

Try out this approach

**simple_class.lua**

```
SimpleClass = {}
SimpleClass.__index = SimpleClass

function SimpleClass:new()
    local obj = {}
    setmetatable(obj, SimpleClass)
    obj.name = "yolo"
    return obj
end
```

**example.lua**

```
require "simple_class"

local instance = SimpleClass:new()

print(instance.name)
-- yolo
```

---

For more help, I'd check out this [Simple Lua Classes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses) from the Lua users wiki

Answer (score 1):

A "props" table is returned by `SimpleClass:new()`: this function mimics creating a new "instance" of "class" SimpleClass. Hence if you do

```
p = SimpleClass:new()
```

then `p` is the `props` table instance created by the `new(self)` function of `SimpleClass` table:

```
print(p.name)
```

will print "yolo".

It is important to understand that you get a new table, which inside `SimpleClass:new()` is bound to a local var called "props", every time you call `SimpleClass:new()`. But you can't get "the props table from SimpleClass": the table that was referenced by `props` in `SimpleClass.new(self)` represents an instance of SimpleClass class. The `SimpleClass` table does not have a table called props.